# Community Toolkit Popup closing on window minimize or maximize in .net MAUI

Tags: maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

I am working with the Community toolkit, after opening the Popup when I minimize or maximize the window the popup gets closed.

**To reproduce the issue please follow the below steps.**

- Run the attached project.
- Click on the button to open the popup.
- Minimize and Maximize the window.
- See the popup is getting closed.

  [Get the project from here](https://github.com/deviprasad987/Bugs.git)

**Expected behavior:**
Popup should not close when the window is minimized or maximized.

**Basic Information**

Visual Studio: Visual Studio 2022 version 17.5 Preview 1.0

Community Toolkit Version: 2.0.0

Affected Platform : Windows SDK 10.0.19041.0

Comment: This is because you have CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup set to true. When the window is closed, the popup loses focus so it closes. If you do not want it to close, set ```CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup = false;```

Comment: @tval I have added CanBeDismissedByTappingOutsideOfPopup = false; as well but still popup closing on minimize or maximize.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate your issue and there is a known issue about this problem.

You can follow it up here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/774.

Thanks for your feedback and patience.